# Reinforcement learning ddpg over fitting problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am using DRL DDPG to optimize portfolio selection of financial assets. When trained - it shows good results. However when test on new data it fails. What could be the reason? Is it a problem of feature engineering? Hyperparameters tuning?

I tried some tuning like gamma and buffer size but it does not help much. Still model shows no predictive value.

I also tried random agent and it actually gives much better results than a trained agent:

```
while not dones:
#   action, _states = model.predict(obs)
action = env.get_attr('action_sample')
obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
```

(self.action_sample = self.action_space.sample())

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Various reason, such as lack of regularization or that one can't predict using your features. To be more precise, we need much more information than what you provided.

Comment: My env has historical OHLCV data for various instruments. I can see that it learn on historical data and when running the model on historical data it is profitable. However it fails on new data.